# asp.net mvc: Error1: Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a signup page. it works in my local computer, but after I deployed to the production.  Kept getting following error message

```
            Server Error in '/' Application.

            Error1: Value cannot be null.
            Parameter name: view

            Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

            Exception Details: System.Exception: Error1: Value cannot be null.
            Parameter name: view

            Source Error: 

            An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

            Stack Trace: 


            [Exception: Error1: Value cannot be null.
            Parameter name: view]
               Smoothie.Web.Controllers.AccountController.Signup(UserRegisterViewModel user, String returnUrl) +662
               lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +149
               System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
               System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +181
               System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
               System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +56
               System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +256
               System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +22
               System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +190
               System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +311
               System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +105
               System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +88
               System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
               System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +34
               System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +19
               System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
               System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
               System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +31
               System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
               System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +23
               System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
               System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
               System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9690172
               System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Here's my code,  I spent whole day to debug it, still no luck.

```
    //[ChildActionOnly]
    public virtual ActionResult Signup(string returnUrl)
    {
       return PartialView(MVC.Account.Views._Register, new UserRegisterViewModel());
        //return PartialView("_Register", new UserRegisterViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult Signup(UserRegisterViewModel user, string returnUrl)
    {
        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var newUser = _mappingService.Map<UserRegisterViewModel, User>(user);

                if (newUser == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("newUser cannot be null");
                }

                var confirmation = _userService.AddUser(newUser, AccountType.Smoothie);

                if (confirmation.WasSuccessful)
                {
                    var userData = _mappingService.Map<User, UserDataDto>(confirmation.Value);

                    if (userData == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("userData cannot be null");
                    }

                    _authenticationService.SetAuthCookie(Response, userData.DisplayName, false, userData);

                    Utilities.SendEmail(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailReply"],
                                        new List<string> {userData.Email}, "Welcome to putastrawinit.com",
                                        GetWelcomeEmail());

                    var redirectUrl = "/home";
                    if (returnUrl != null && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                    {
                        redirectUrl = returnUrl;
                    }


                    return Json(new {Success = true, RedirectUrl = redirectUrl});
                    //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", null);


                }

                ModelState.AddModelError("", confirmation.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error1: " + e.Message);
        }

        var errors = from value in ModelState.Values
                     from error in value.Errors
                     select new { error.ErrorMessage };

        //throw new Exception("Errors: " + errors.ToString());

        return Json(new { Success = false, ErrorMessages = errors });
    }
```

sign up view page.

```
            @model Smoothie.Domain.ViewModels.UserRegisterViewModel
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Signup", "Account", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSignupSuccess", OnFailure = "onSignupFailure" }))
            {

                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", null, new { value = @Request.QueryString["returnUrl"] })    
                <div class="signupForm">
                    <div>@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @id = "signupSummary" })</div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="Email">
                            Display Name:</label>
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DisplayName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="Email">
                            Email Address:</label>
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new {@class = "text-box", autocomplete = "off" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="Password">
                            Password:</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("Password", null, new { @class = "registerPassword text-box", type = "password", autocomplete = "off" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label>
                            &nbsp;</label>
                        <div class="registerChecker">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label>
                            &nbsp;</label>
                        <input type="image" src="@Links.Content.images.btn_sign_up_png" style="width: 91px; height: 33px;" value="Create" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

this is the ViewModel.

```
            using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

            namespace Smoothie.Domain.ViewModels
            {
                public class UserRegisterViewModel
                {
                    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
                    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Email must be 50 characters or fewer")]
                    [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Your Email address is invalid")]
                    public string Email { get; set; }

                    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Display name is required")]
                    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Display name must be between 2 and 25 characters")]
                    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

                    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
                    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
                    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Password must be between 8 and 25 characters")]
                    public string Password { get; set; }
                }
            }
```

this is the new stack trace after I removed try catch from the code.

```
        Value cannot be null.
        Parameter name: view

        Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

        Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
        Parameter name: view

        Source Error: 

        An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

        Stack Trace: 


        [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
        Parameter name: view]
           System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext..ctor(ControllerContext controllerContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, TempDataDictionary tempData, TextWriter writer) +205
           Smoothie.Web.Controllers.AccountController.GetWelcomeEmail() +178
           Smoothie.Web.Controllers.AccountController.Signup(UserRegisterViewModel user) +288
           lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +106
           System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
           System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +181
           System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
           System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +56
           System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +256
           System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +22
           System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +190
           System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +311
           System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +105
           System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +88
           System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
           System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +34
           System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +19
           System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
           System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
           System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +31
           System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
           System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +23
           System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
           System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
           System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9690172
           System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by my routes. route is : /Account/Signup, I also post the view page at the bottom, hopefully it helps.

Comment: @Steve, line 662  public virtual ActionResult Signup(UserRegisterViewModel user, string returnUrl)

Comment: show us the model definition plz

Comment: @Steve, i added the model at the bottom of the post.

Comment: you never want to rethrow an exception inside catch, that DESTROYS stacktrace. change the throw new exception to just throw; and show us the new stacktrace

Comment: @Steve, i added hte new stack trace.  now sure how much it will help. what drive me crazy is it works in local but not produciton.

Comment: The issue lies in your constructor. It's expecting `IView view` but `view` is null. Are you using dependency injection? Is your production server missing some assemblies?

Comment: @webnoob, yes, i am using autofac. should have everything there. I have another method "login", it works fine.

Comment: Can you post your constructor for this controller please?

Comment: Actually, it's not the AccountController constructor that's at fault here. What's in `GetWelcomeEmail`?

Comment: @webnoob, thank you so much. You are right, view is missing for welcomemessage.  i upload it, it works now. cannot believe it took me all day. thank you so much.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer in that case :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the latest call stack, it looks like the view is missing from `GetWelcomeEmail()` which is causing `view` to be null in the ViewContexts constructor.

Comment: i tried them both in my local computer, they both work. then tried them both in production, they both didnt' work.  must be something else.

Comment: not sure what you mean by my routes. route is : /Account/Signup, I also post the view page at the bottom, hopefully it helps.

Comment: @feelexit - It might be worth removing these old comments as they are for the answer I previously posted.